# Функция определена, но при вызове из метода все равно получаю ошибку NameError

Tags: python, функции

При вызове метода nod выдает ошибку : name 'nod' is not defined Как можно исправить?

```
class Tests:
    def nod(a, b):
       #вычисляю нод

    def testFerma(n):
        k = nod(a,n)

    f = open("Numbers.txt", 'r')
    for line in f:
      line = int(line)
      if(line >=5 and line %2!=0):
         testFerma(line)

    f.close
```

Comment: В вопросе с отступами проблема. Либо делайте тестирование отдельным классом, а не внутри

Comment: Простое решение - убрать класс вообще, он тут не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

В питоне в метод всегда надо передавать `self`.
В функции не может быть только комменты (для этого есть ключевое слово `pass`).

`f.close()`со скобками

```
class Tests():
    def nod(self, a, b):
       #вычисляю нод
       pass

    def testFerma(self, n):
        k = self.nod(a,n)
        f = open("Numbers.txt", 'r')
        for line in f:
          line = int(line)
          if(line >= 5 and line %2!=0):
             self.testFerma(line)

        f.close()
```

Comment: f = open("Numbers.txt", 'r')
        for line in f:
          line = int(line)
          if(line >=5 and line %2!=0):
             self.testFerma(line)

        f.close() Находится вне кода, и в таком случае, ругается, что self не определен

Comment: "В питоне в метод всегда надо передавать self." - не всегда, в статический метод не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

1. У вас полный бардак с методами. Либо объявите их как статические методы, либо добавьте первый аргумент self.
2. Нельзя вызвать метод, просто написав его имя. Метод всегда относится к чему-то.

Нужно либо так:

```
k = Tests.nod(a,n)
```

либо, что более разумно, нужно вообще вынести nod из класса наверх, чтобы это была просто функция, а не метод.